# Numeronym generation

Tags: javascript, algorithm, strings, compression

#### Problem statement

I need to generate [numeronyms from a string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeronym), let's say `qwerty` as follows:

```
qwerty
q1erty
q2rty
q3ty
q4y
```

#### Code

Can this solution can be **improved** or if there's any **better approach**?

```js
const str = 'qwerty';
const lastCharPos = str.length - 1;

str
  .split('')
  .map(
    (_, i) =>
      i !== lastCharPos &&
      console.log(`${str[0]}${i ? i : ''}${str.slice(i + 1, lastCharPos)}${str[lastCharPos]}`)
  );
```

Comment: .... why? How is it compression? How do you decompress?

Comment: Compress is probably not the right word, this looks like a [numeronym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeronym) which seems to have many names (alphanumeric acronyms, alphanumeric abbreviations, or numerical contractions), e.g. `a11y` for accessibility, `i18n` for internationalization, etc.

Comment: Do you need all the intermediary strings?

Comment: @Setris exactly, thanks for correcting me with that!

Answer (score 2):

### Know the language

Part of being a programmer is being familiar with the language/s you are using. These days languages are changing yearly thus keeping up to date is very important. [MDN JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) provides a good JavaScript reference. Every now and then its good to peruse the site to keep your knowledge up to date.

### Strings

[String.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) will slice to the end of the string if you don't include the second argument. Thus there is no need for the variable `lastCharPos`

If the arguments for [String.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) are negative the position of the slice if from the end of the string. eg `"abcd".slice(-2)` will return `"cd"`

You can [String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) a string using [... (Spread syntax)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) spread operator. eg`[...str].map`

### Arrays

[Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) creates an array. You do not use the array and so you should have used [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Often when using arrays and their iteration functions like `map`, it forces you to adapt the code to fit the array function's needs, increasing the complexity of the source and at runtime.  You do this twice...

1. The need to soak the first argument of map `map((_, i) =>` which is a hack in my view.
2. As you have no control over the number of iterations you are forced to add two statements `i !== lastCharPos` and `i ?`  in the ternary expression `i ? i : ''`

### Improving the code.

Always make your code portable by wrapping it in a function

Code should be focused on one task (role) at a time. Because you created the code inline (not a function) you have combined various tasks into one.

1. Creating the set of strings
2. Outputting to the console.

As a function you can separate the output from the creation, returning an array of strings that you can then use as needed. eg Output to console.

The Array iteration functions are too cumbersome for what your code does. You can use a [while](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) loop and push the built string to an array which you return at the end.

### Rewrite

Your function does not output anything if the string length is <= 1. It is unclear if this is just an output requirement. The rewrite will return the input string (as first item in the array) no matter what its size

The string is sliced using a negative index to slice from the end of the string.

I used a [while](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) loop but you can also use a [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop

Using while loop

```
function numeronyms(str) {
    const result = [str], len = str.length;
    var i = 1;
    while (i < len - 1) { result.push(str[0] + (i++) + str.slice(i - len)) }
    return result;
}
```

Using for loop

```
function numeronyms(str) {
    const result = [str], len = str.length;
    for (let i = 2; i < len; i ++) {
        result.push(str[0] + (i - 1) + str.slice(i - len));
    }
    return result;
}
```

### Usage

To use the function so that it behaves the same as your code it needs to check the string length.

```
const str = "qwerty";
if (str.length > 1) { console.log(numeronyms(str)) }
```

or

```
const str = "qwerty";
str.length > 1 && console.log(numeronyms(str));
```

Or just assign the array for use later

```
const numers = numeronyms("qwerty");
```

Answer (score 2):

A short review;

- You want to put this in a function
- That function should either create the numeronyms or do the outputting, not both
- You are using `&&` as an `if` statement, great for code golfing, not so great for code review
- Using `.map()` doesnt really make sense if you are not actually mapping, `.forEach()` makes more sense
- If you insist on `split` and `map` as a for loop, consider to `split` on str.substr(1)
- I would store the first and last character in a nicely named variable for better comprehension

A counter proposal would be

```js
function generateNumeronyms(s){
  
  const out = [s], start = s[0];
  let i = 1, tail = s.substring(2);
        
  while(tail){
    out.push(start + i++ + tail);
    tail = tail.substring(1);
  }
  return out;
}


console.log(generateNumeronyms('qwerty').join('\n'));
```